# Can't register vb.net express 2012 without company name

Tags: .net, vb.net

I downloaded vb.net 2012 express a couple weeks ago and the registry has run out. I tried to fill out the forms online to obtain a registry key, but it requires company information. I'm not part of a company. How do i register?

Answer (score 4):

Just use "Home" or "Home User" as your company name. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/Vsexpressinstall/thread/9fcfc48e-89e5-4819-acf5-158fa1889a71